# Getting 405 Method Not Allowed on a GET

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7.5

Clicking the following link in my webapp produces a 405:

```
<a href="/unsubscribe/confirm?emailUid=<%= ViewData["emailUid"] %>&hash=<%= ViewData["hash"] %>" class="button">Yes, unsubscribe me.</a>
```

Here's the Confirm Action being called from the Unsubscribe Controller:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Confirm( string emailUid, string hash)
    {
        using ( UnsubscribeClient client = new UnsubscribeClient() )
        {
            UnsubscribeResponse response = client.Unsubscribe( emailUid, hash );
            return View( response );
        }

    }
```

Simple stuff. It works when I F5 it, but when I host it in IIS (both 7.5 and 6), I get the error.

I'm pretty lost with this. I've scoured the net, but can't seem to find any reason as to why this is happening.

Comment: did you try cast data as string?  (string)ViewData["emailUid"]  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found my issue. It turns out to be a problem with my IIS configuration. In IIS 6, I didn't allow scripts to be executed in the directory, so my .svc would never run for my service host. Once I changed that setting, I no longer received the 405 error...

Many thanks to the other answers. I'll be sure to use the Html helper.

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "Yes, unsubscribe me.",
    "Confirm", 
    "Unsubscribe", 
    new { emailUid = ViewData["emailUid"], hash = ViewData["hash"] }, 
    new { @class = "button" }
) %>
```

Also `ViewData`?! Please, remove this as well in favor of strongly typed views and view models. Everytime I see someone using `ViewData` I feel obliged to say that.

Answer (score 0):

What is the actual rendered HTML href in the anchor? Is the generated URI valid?

Does changing it to this work:

```
 <%= Html.ActionLink("Yes, unsubscribe me.", "Confirm", "Unsubscribe", new { emailUid= ViewData["emailUid"], hash = ViewData["hash"]})%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the outputted URL is valid and any invalid character is escaped properly, for exaple make sure `&` are escaped as `&amp;`

Answer (score 0):

If there is a period in your `emailUid` or `hash`, it needs to be encoded.  That's not the only problematic character, but I suspect it is the case here.  Use [`HttpUtility.UrlEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlencode.aspx) on these values before concatenating them into the URL.

Why the 405?  Likely because there is no script mappings in IIS6 for the presumed "file extension".  It's not a file extension at all, but without encoding the period in the URL it doesn't know any better.